# NMDS gives conflicting results to ANOSIM and ADONIS

Tags: vegan

I am testing differences in community composition between fished and no-take areas, and while the nmds seems to indicate the two levels overlap considerably, ANOSIM and ADONIS suggest there are significant differences. Have I done something wrong or is there a reason for this significant difference that I can't see?

```
species

env=species[,1]
species=species[,-1]
species = species[,colSums(species) > 2]

nmds=metaMDS(species, distance="bray", k=3, type="n", trymax=100)
nmds
env$Protection=as.factor(env$Protection)
pointvec <- c(21, 21)
bgvec <- c("black","white")
with(env, levels(Protection))
plot(nmds,type="n",xaxt='n',xlab="",cex.lab=1.5,cex.axis=1.4,xlim=c(-1.5,1.5),ylim=c(-1.2,1))
axis(side=1)
with(env, points(nmds,pch=pointvec[Protection],cex=1,bg = bgvec[Protection],type="p" ,display="sites"))
ordiellipse(nmds, groups=env$Protection, kind = "se", conf = 0.95)
legend("topleft", "A", bty="n",cex=1.5,inset=-0.02,adj=1) 
legend("bottomright", "Stress = 0.182", bty="n",cex=1.5) 
with(env,legend("topright", legend =  levels(Protection),inset=-0.007,cex=1.5,bty="n",pt.bg =    bgvec,pch=pointvec))
```

[image: nmds plot showing close overlap of groups]

```
spe.dist <- vegdist(species,method='bray')
spe.ano <- anosim(spe.dist, env$Protection)
summary(spe.ano)

#Call:
#anosim(x = spe.dist, grouping = env$Protection) 
#Dissimilarity: bray 

#ANOSIM statistic R: 0.04693 
      #Significance: 0.029 

#Permutation: free
#Number of permutations: 999

#Upper quantiles of permutations (null model):
   #90%    95%  97.5%    99% 
#0.0290 0.0398 0.0487 0.0593 

#Dissimilarity ranks between and within classes:
       # 0%     25%     50%     75% 100%    N
#Between  1 655.625 1193.50 1771.25 2317 1184
#fished   3 750.500 1360.00 1896.50 2317  666
 #no-take  2 358.125  837.25 1525.00 2285  496
```

And then the permanova gives a similar result

```
adonis(species~env$Protection,method='bray')

#Call:
#adonis(formula = species ~ env$Protection, method = "bray") 
#Permutation: free
#Number of permutations: 999
#Terms added sequentially (first to last)

              # Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)   
#env$Protection  1    0.9517 0.95174  2.8946 0.04141  0.002 **
#Residuals      67   22.0296 0.32880         0.95859          
#Total          68   22.9813                 1.00000          
 #---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the NMDS graphics and your tests are inconsistent: tests are for the location of class *centroids*, but the graph shows the spread of *observations*. `ordiellipse(..., kind = "se", conf = 0.95)` would be more consistent with the tests. Secondly, the tests (in particular, `adonis` -- I would not use `anosim`) are based on the full *n*-dimensional space interpreted as Euclidean, whereas NMDS is a two-dimensional mapping of a non-Euclidean dissimilarity (although the NMDS plot itself is Euclidean). It may be that your groups differ in third dimension that you have not estimated.

Comment: thanks @Jari Oksanen. I have edited the question to include ordiellipse instead. It does still present considerable overlap. Is there another way to display the data to see these differences in the third dimension? It also seems strange that the R squared is so low (0.04) and yet there is still a significant difference. Does this make sense?